# ERR_ABORTED 404 - Django - Static Files

Tags: python, django, apache, static-files

I get the following error in my web site:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/project/static/js/stylish-portfolio.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

I don't understand why, because all my static files are in chmod 775.

May be it's due to my setting file, but i don't see the issue. :/

My setting file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
GPAAS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = '/project/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(GPAAS_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(GPAAS_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/project/media/'
```

I use:

- Apache 2.4.35
- Python 3.6.5
- Django 2.2.4

Has anyone ever had this issue, or may be some advice to solve this problem?

Could you help me please?

**EDIT :**

My project is like that :

```
.
└── DjangoMainFolder
    ├── DjangoApp
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── DjangoApp
    │   │       ├── custom.css
    │   │       └── custom.js
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── DjangoApp
    │   │       ├── base.html
    │   │       └── z_AND_SO_ON
    │   └── z_AND_SO_ON
    └── DjangoProjectFiles
    |    ├── settings.py
    |    ├── urls.py
    |    └── wsgi.py
    |__ static
         |__ img
         |__ js
         |__ css
```

I would like use the file static `DjangoMainFolder/static/`, not the static in my APP.

Comment: Are you working on Debug mode? And did you add static url into your urlpatterns?

Comment: It works in local with `debug = True`. But in my apache server with `debug = False`, i get an error. I don't understand your second question, which 'static url' ? And why is my 'urlpatterns' ?

Comment: Never mind, I though that you're on Debug mode. So that might be because your apache config file, I think it could provide more information if you can add that file into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have static files directive declared in INSTALLED_APPS?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Also, try `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and don't forget to put as the first line inside your html: `{% load staticfiles %}`

Later edit:
`{% load staticfiles %}` is the correct syntax, when referring them inside the template you use `{% static '/DjangoApp/FileName.extension' %}`
considering you use the following project structure:

```
.
└── DjangoMainFolder
    ├── DjangoApp
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── DjangoApp
    │   │       ├── custom.css
    │   │       └── custom.js
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── DjangoApp
    │   │       ├── base.html
    │   │       └── z_AND_SO_ON
    │   └── z_AND_SO_ON
    └── DjangoProjectFiles
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Yes I have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`. And my first line in my html is : `{%load static%}`, the correct word is it static or staticfiles ? I gonna try `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: {% load staticfiles %} is the correct syntax, when referring them inside the template you use {% static '/DjangoApp/FileName.extension' %}